# mclapply user time larger than elapsed time

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing

I am trying to use `mclapply` function of the `parallel` package in `R`. The function is assigning the values to sequence matrix by calculating log likelihood distance - a CPU-intensive operation.

The resulting `system.time` values are confusing:

```
> system.time(mclapply(worksample,function(x){p_seqi_modj(x,worksample[[1]],c(1:17))}))
   user  system elapsed 
 29.339   1.242  18.581
```

I thought that `elapsed` means aggregated time (`user`+`system`). What does the above result mean in this case and to what time should I orient myself? My unparallelized version takes less in `user` time and much more in `elapsed`.

Comment: The question is what do you care about?  Most people want the results sooner which corresponds to elapsed time.

Answer (score 4):

The help page `?system.time` says the value returned by the function  is an object of class proc_time, and that we should consult `?proc.time`. There we learn that user time is

```
cumulative sum of user and system times of any child processes
```

so your task has spent about 15s on each core (`mclapply` defaults to using 2 cores, see the `mc.cores` argument).

Actually, we see earlier in the help page that `proc.time()` returns five elements that separate the process and child times, and that the summary method used in printing collapses the user and system time into process + child times, so there is a bit more information available.

Comment: just to reiterate and make sure I understand, this means that the elapsed time is the time that actually passed from beginning to end of the operation, and the user time is the sum of all spent times across all cores ( in my case 2) . So if I ran in parallel on 2 cores, each spent 15 sec to finish the task ( together ~30 sec), but the total elapsed time is only 18 sec, precisely due to the tasks executed in parallel. Is this correct?

Comment: This answer isn't right because you're reading the help file incorrectly.  `proc.time()` returns 5 values, and the 4th and 5th values are "4: (cumulative sum of user [time of any child process]) and 5: (system times of any child processes)".